# Can a fragment be created from an extension of the Application class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-application-class

I have a background task that occasionally prompts the user with dialogs and I would like it to run through the life of the application. Right now everything is controlled from a task fragment. So I was wondering if it is possible to create this fragment from a custom application class that extends `Application` and if so how can you do it?

Comment: "I would like it to run through the life of the application" -- what does this mean, in programming terms? "So I was wondering if it is possible to create this fragment from a class that extends Application" -- no, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` class in android extends from `android.app.Fragment`. `Application` class extends from `android.app.Application`.
If you want to launch your fragment from your application just do it using `fragmentManager` in Android.